# React Router v6 Private Routes - With Moralis api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, moralis

I don't understand why this code is not working. "isAuthenticated" is a boolean from the moralis API. If it is true it should render outlet and if it's false should render the navigate option.

```
const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useMoralis();
  return isAuthenticated ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/" />;
};

return (
  <Routes>
    <Route path={ROUTER_PATHS.SIGNUP} element={<Signup />} />
    <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
      <Route path={ROUTER_PATHS.EMPLOYER} element={<MarketPlaceEmployer />} />
      <Route path={ROUTER_PATHS.EMPLOYEE} element={<MarketPlaceEmployee />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and explain in detail, what's the problem

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Does the `useMoralis` hook do *some* asynchronous check prior to confirming a user's authentication status? From what I can see of the code you've shared there's no issue, it's what I'd expect to write for a route protection component, so I suspect the issue is elsewhere or it is just a logical issue. Please clarify what the issue is.

Answer (score -1):

Using `<Outlet />` component will make `ProtectedRoutes` component as Layout component to make `ProtectedRoutes` work as wrapping component as well you should optionally render children, change `ProtectedRoutes` component as,

```
const ProtectedRoutes = ({ children }) => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useMoralis();
  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to="/" />;
  }
  return children ? children : <Outlet />;
};
```

Also, add `exact` before `path`,

```
 return (
<Routes>
  <Route path={ROUTER_PATHS.SIGNUP} element={<Signup />} />
  <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
    <Route exact path={ROUTER_PATHS.EMPLOYER} element={<MarketPlaceEmployer />} />
    <Route exact path={ROUTER_PATHS.EMPLOYEE} element={<MarketPlaceEmployee />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```